How can I log in to Samba Domain Controller with domain account?
I have provisioned my server to domain controller using samba
sudo samba-tool domain provision \
    --interactive \
    --use-rfc2307 \
    --backend-store=mdb \
    --backend-store-size=16Gb \
    --function-level=2016 \
    --option="ad dc functional level = 2016"

I can join other machines to domain (using sssd) and log in to them using my domain accounts.
But I cannot login to my domain controller with my domain administrator account. I tried sssd, but in every instruction I saw - I need to join computer to domain (but I'm already in the domain as a domain controller). Can anyone tell me if it is possible and if so, how can I do it?
While I try to log in
sudo login administrator@domain.name
I'm getting error - user not found
If I
id administrator@domain.name
or
id administrator
I also get id: «administrator@domain.name»: There is no such user

There are primarily two AD "domain join" clients: RedHat's SSSD and Samba's own Winbind. (The latter has actually existed for much longer than SSSD and very nearly predates AD as a whole, so it's strange that you have not found any instructions for using it.)
A Samba domain controller will always be running a self-joined 'winbindd' process as part of the AD DC service, which lets you install the PAM and Glibc nsswitch modules for interfacing with it (e.g. lib{nss,pam}-winbind on Debian).
Load the winbind module (libnss_winbind.so) from your /etc/nsswitch.conf for passwd & group information retrieval (i.e. this makes id administrator work), then add the pam_winbind module to your /etc/pam.d to handle password authentication.
(Or preferably, don't. There isn't anything you could do when logged in as a Domain Admin that you cannot do when logged in as root – whenever Samba breaks you will have to log in as root anyway, while most of the regular Domain Admin tasks are better done from a separate machine.)

Thanks, that gave a direction. I've
apt install lib{nss,pam}-winbind
then checked that there is libnss_winbind.so.2 in my samba lib directory, made links to system path
ln -s $path/libnss_winbind.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_winbind.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_winbind.so
edited /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         files winbind group:          files winbind
Checked that wbinfo --ping-dc succeed, but id administrator or id administrator@domain.name steel doesnt work

@НикитаГрубов: The fact that you needed to make those links manually is suspicious, as the libnss-winbind package already installs to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ in the first place, so what $path did you use and where did you get it from?
